# Cannot open a website in R using $navigate

Tags: r, docker, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am following some of the steps from this [case](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-vs-r-what-i-learned-from-4-000-job-advertisements-ab41661b7f28), but I am stuck in the very beginning of opening a webpage with Rselenium.
I have downloaded the [Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/) and installed the [chrome-driver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), as suggested by this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-web-browser-automation-with-selenium-and-docker-containers-c1bcbcb91540).
But, after running the codes below I get the error message as follows:

```
rm(list=ls())
gc()
#
# Run the next line inside the docker
# docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
#### PACKAGES ####
library(RSelenium)  
library(rvest)  
library(dplyr)  
library(data.table)
#
eCaps <- list(
  chromeOptions = 
    list(prefs = list(
      "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
      "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
      "download.default_directory" = "C://Users/MYFOLDER/Downloads"
    ))) #Blocks popups, free download and define folder for downloads
#
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName="chrome", 
                      port=4445L,
                      extraCapabilities = eCaps,
                      remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",)
# Remote server addres vem do Docker, docker-machine ip
remDr$open
remDr$getStatus()
remDr$navigate("www.jobserve.co.uk")
```

Then I get

```
> remDr$navigate("www.jobserve.co.uk")
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe try `remDr$navigate("http://www.jobserve.co.uk")`?

Comment: It was written like that before and also did not work...I copied and pasted after tried changing it